# REST API - Best Practice for Multiple GetByX in Controller

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-url, restful-architecture

So this should be a pretty easy one. In fact I've read lots of Q&A's on much more complicated Restful Design problems out there and I did not find the answer to this simple one... So if I have the following entity:

```
public class Guest 
{
   public int GuestId { get; set; }
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   // bunch of other properties
}
```

What should my `GuestController` look like if I want to have methods available to retrieve a `Guest` object via the `GuestId` or the `PersonId`?

I know I could accomplish this by it looking something like this..

```
public class GuestsController
{
    // GET api/guests/1
    public Guest Get(int id)
    {
        // get the Guest by GuestId
    }

    // GET api/guests/GetbyPersonId/2
    public Guest GetbyPersonId(int personId)
    {
        // get the Guest by PersonId
    }
}
```

... and then using attribute routing or actions or whatever to reach the `GetByPersonId` method, but that just doesn't seem to comply with the whole Restful design principles I've been reading about. What is suggested in this case?

Comment: I might suggest mapping `/people/{personId}/guest` to `GetGuestByPersonId`, assuming that `guest` is a one-to-one relation of `person`.

Answer (score 0):

I Edited my answer,
I would suggest you use better logical hierarchy url to map your impelementation. 
so I would change the url structure to below.

```
// /api/people/{Id}/
public class PersonRequest
{
   public int PersonId {get; set;}
}

//  /api/people/{Id}/guest
public class GuestRequest : PersonRequest
{

}
```

after using the better hierachy url structure, I think it much clearer you only provide Get by `Person Id` implementation and there is no need for Get By `Guest Id`

```
public class PersonService
{
  public object Get(PersonRequest request)
  {
    return GuestController.Get(request.PersonId);
  }

  public object Get(GuestRequest request)
  {
    return GuestController.Get(request.PersonId);
  }

}
```

Comment: I edited my post as I had a mistake which might have given you the wrong impression, I want both methods to return a Guest object. So basically it will be like search for a Guest by GuestId and another method searching for a Guest by PersonId. While your example works for returning a Guest or Person by their respective primary keys, it does not work for my requirement. Any more thoughts?

Comment: I updated the answer, is that what you looking for ?